# how to resize terminal.app's window pixelwise?

Tags: terminal, iterm, window-manager

Terminal.app's window size always fit the rows and columns of its content, which make it impossible to maximize the window (always leaving a gap).

[image: pic]

I know iterm.app has an [option](https://superuser.com/questions/581889/iterm-2-window-resizing#:%7E:text=Open%20Preferences%20%3E%20Profiles%20%3E%20Text%20%3E,size%20lands%20where%20you%20want.) regarding this. Can I change this behavior in terminal.app too?

Comment: What exactly is your question here? And what is shown by the picture/screenshot? Please edit the question to add details.

Comment: After your edit - do you actually mean fullscreen, or maximised? Dragging would imply maximised. Double-clicking the corner when the cursor changes to a double arrow should maximise as far as the window will go. There will always be a small gap at the bottom, reserved for activating the Dock.

Comment: @Tets I hide my dock, it's an issue specific to terminal, other apps like chrome don't behave like this. AFAIK iterm and emacs also have this behavior, more like a feature. but you can turn them off (https://superuser.com/questions/581889 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758800), I want to know if it

Comment: is possible to turn this behavior off in terminal.app

Comment: It resizes in increments of character rows and columns, not arbitrary pixels.

Comment: @Marc exactly, I'm bad at phrasing to point this out. I just wonder if it's possible to change this behavior, like you can do in iterm or Emacs.

Answer (score 2):

Terminal.app resizes in (character) rows and columns, not in pixels. There is (at least up to and including macOS Monterey) no option to change this.

Comment: well, that's a bummer. thanks for your information.